# How to convert explicitly from const type to type, in C?

Tags: c

If I compile the following code (in file *"myfile.c"*) by gcc:

```
void bar(int *pi)
{
    /* do something */
}

foo(const int *pi)
{
    bar(pi);
}
```

Using the following command line:

```
gcc    myfile.c    -ansi    -pedantic-errors
```

I get the following error:

```
error: passing argument 1 of 'bar' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]  
    bar(pi);

note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'const int *'
    void bar(int *pi)
```

My question is, without changing the command line, how to avoid this error? e.i. just by writing some code in `foo`, because I can't change `bar` and `foo` prototypes.

Comment: `bar(pi)` -> `bar((int *)pi)` -- but I sense an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Casting away `const` is very rarely a good idea.

Comment: Consider `#define CONST_CAST(type, value) ((type)(value))` in C, which can be `#define CONST_CAST(type, value) const_cast<type>(value)` in C++.  I don't often use it, but it documents what's happening when I do.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your actual problem? Why can't you change the prototypes and why do you think casting away `const` solves your problem? I can't tell for sure, but I assume there's a better way.

Comment: Wrong way! You can't. removing the `const` invokes undefined behaviour and can break your code just at a different layer. Write const-correct code. Normally there is a reason for both, `const` and non-`const` parameters. If that is some library, get a modern (since ca. 18 years) version.

Comment: @FelixPalmen sure: I want to use `void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));`, from the c standard library, which takes a `compar` function as a parameter. But inside the body of my my `compar` function, I want to call another function which take one of the `compar` parameters as a parameter, but it doesn't require it to be a `const`.

Comment: @BiteBytes then this other function is very likely to modify what its parameter points to in some cases, so it shouldn't be used in a `compar` function. (but then, you could indeed take a copy as dasblinkenlight's answer suggests)

Comment: @FelixPalmen I can use the method shown by dasblinkenlight

Comment: @Olaf it isn't necessarily UB, because the *effective type* of the object could be non-`const`, but in practice, I can't think of any sensible example (ab)using this, so I mostly agree with you here.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: From 6.5p7 "_An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types: … a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,_". - So while it is allowed to add qualifiers, it is not allowed to "un-qualify". But yes, it basically depends on the ET of the oribinal object. If OP can guarantee it is **never ever** `const` qualified, it wouuld be formally correct. Nevertheless there will be no support by the compiler. Nothing someone having to ask this question should actually do.

Comment: @Olaf this is just elaborating my point further. As surprising as this may be, we fully agree here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `const`-ness can be cast away, as long as the actual pointer points to a non-`const` location:

```
foo(const int *pi) {
    bar((int*)pi); // <<== Be very careful with this!
}
```

The assumption here is that `pi` is really a non-`const` pointer, so the best course of action is to have the compiler enforce it by removing `const` from `foo`'s declaration:

```
void foo(int *pi) { // Remove const
    ...
}
```

If you cannot do that, and since `bar` takes an `int` pointer without `const` qualifier, you need to pass it a location that can be written. For example, if this is a single item, not an array, you could make a copy of what the pointer points to, and pass that to the function:

```
void bar(int *pi, size_t n) {
    /* do something */
}
foo(const int *pi) {
    int tmp = *pi;
    bar(&tmp);
}
```

If `pi` points to an array of `n` elements, you would need to make a temporary buffer for it:

```
void bar(int *pi, size_t n) {
    /* do something */
}
foo(const int *pi, size_t n) {
    int *buf = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    memcpy(buf, pi, sizeof(int) * n);
    bar(buf, n);
    free(buf);
}
```

Comment: Actually I can't change `foo`'s prototype neither, I updated my question

Comment: @BiteBytes Then you should make a copy, just to make sure the code does not exhibit undefined behavior when `pi` points to a location that happens to be `const`.